# BaseAdapter: set hasStableIds() to false?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` that uses a subclass of `BaseAdapter`. The adapter uses item indices (positions) as ids and thus the ids are not stable (one of the operations on the underlying data is swapping between two data items).

Do I need to override in my adapter `hasStableIds()` to `return false`?

Looking at the `BaseAdapter` here suggest

> that false is the default

.

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java

```
// Is this required? Isn't this the default?
@Override
public final boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public final long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you do not need to override `hasStableIds()` if you want the default behavior because its a method of [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#hasStableIds%28%29) interface which the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#hasStableIds%28%29) implements through [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and [SpinnerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) and therefore has to provide a default implementation of that.

However you do need to override `getItemId(int position)` because its an abstract method of BaseAdapter class.

Comment: what should you return for getItemId?