# What is the advantage of setting hasStableIds() to false in BaseAdapter?

Tags: java, android, gridview, baseadapter

I was working with animations in gridview  and found that  `hasStableIds()` was overrided  and returned `true` to maintain  stable id for the items. I want to know  how this affect the performance of my grid view? Is this adding extra overhead of keeping stable Ids for each item?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BaseAdapter: set hasStableIds() to false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919822/baseadapter-set-hasstableids-to-false)

Comment: @Chintan Rathod It says nothing about the performance difference!

Answer (score 2):

In short: no.

`GridView` is not responsible for choosing IDs, so there is no overhead whatsoever here. IDs are supplied by the data source. Returning `true` in `hasStableIds()` is not a way to *request* stable IDs, but to tell `GridView` that you are *providing* the said stability.

So the overhead, if any, is in the code retrieving data.
In the typical situation (extraction from a database), IDs are persistent by default.

So why does `GridView` care about IDs' stability? To do a couple of interesting tricks that may actually *improve* performance:

- Different (hopefully faster and/or more robust) handling of configuration changing.
- Ability to return an array of checked IDs if `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` is set, sparing you from remapping positions to IDs.