# hasStableIds () in Expandable ListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am creating app Using ExpandableListView ,I referred some tutorials .The  hasStableIds () set to false? what is the exact need for making hasStableIds() to false?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Documentation of [`hasStableIds()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#hasStableIds%28%29)

> Indicates whether the child and group IDs are stable across changes to the underlying data.
>
> Returns
>   whether or not the same ID always refers to the same object

It's used when you change the data of the Adapter, everytime you change the data the `ExpandableListView` should update it's views to reflect the changes.

If true the `ExpandableListView` can reuse the same `View` if the ID is the same.

If false it should recreate all the views since it can't have any idea what changes.

The ID which i refer is the ID returned by [`getGroupId`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupId%28int%29) and `getItemId`.

You should override this methods too!

Some questions:

- [BaseAdapter: set hasStableIds() to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919822/baseadapter-set-hasstableids-to-false)
- [Android - what is the meaning of StableIDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217416/android-what-is-the-meaning-of-stableids)

Comment: I think you meant `getChildId` instead of `getItemId`.